# Gradient vector function using sum and scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

Could someone take a look on my attempt to compute the gradient for:

$$f(x) = \lambda \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i)$$

Where $x \in \mathbb{R^d}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$$g(x_i) = \begin{cases}
x_i - \varepsilon/2 & \textbf{if } |x_i| \geq \varepsilon\\
x_i^2 / (2\varepsilon) & \textbf{if } |x_i| < \varepsilon\\
\end{cases}$$

This is what I have done so far:

The function $g(x_i)$ is not differentiable if $x = -\varepsilon$, for the rest:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_i}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)=
\begin{cases}
1&|x_i|\ge\epsilon\;,\\
x_i/\epsilon&|x_i|\lt\epsilon\;.
\end{cases}
$$

For $f(x)$ I would apply the product rule:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) &= (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \lambda) \cdot \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i) + \lambda \cdot (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i))\\
&= 0 \cdot \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i) + \lambda \cdot (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i))\\
&= \lambda \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{x = 1}^n g(x_i)
\end{align*}

If this is correct, then my question is of which domain is then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)$?

Either it is $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}$. I am not sure, for the fact, that this is a gradient I would say $\mathbb{R}^n$, but how are then the components of the resulting vector computed?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
???\\
???\\
\vdots\\
???
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} = \lambda g'(x_i)$, so the gradient is given by $\nabla f(x) = \lambda (g'(x_1),...,g'(x_n))^T$

Second, $g'(t) = 1$, when $|t|>\epsilon$, and $g'(t) = \frac{t}{\epsilon}$when $|t| < \epsilon$.

Hence the gradient is either $(\lambda,...,\lambda)^T$ if $||x||_{\infty} < \epsilon$, or $\frac{\lambda}{\epsilon} x$ if $x_i > \epsilon$, $\forall i$. For other $x$, you need to use the appropriate value depending on $x_i$.

No product rule is needed.

And $\nabla f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Finally you brought some light into the darkness.

Comment: Note that I fixed a minor error in the solution; the gradient is $\frac{\lambda}{\epsilon}$ only when **all** $x_i>\epsilon$.